# How to auto accept Skype friend requests in VB.NET using Skype4COMLib?

Tags: vb.net, skype, skype4com, skypedeveloper

Hello everyone so I'm trying to auto accept friend requests on my Skype using VB.NET and Skype4COMLib but I'm getting this error:

> Private Sub oskype_userauthorizationrequestreceived(pUser As SKYPE4COMLib.User)' cannot handle event 'Public Event UserAuthorizationRequestReceived(sender As Object, e As AxSKYPE4COMLib._ISkypeEvents_UserAuthorizationRequestReceivedEvent)' because they do not have a compatible signature.

The code:

```
 Private Sub oskype_userauthorizationrequestreceived(pUser As User) Handles oSkype.UserAuthorizationRequestReceive 
    If MaterialCheckBox7.Checked = True And pUser.IsAuthorized = False Then
        pUser.IsAuthorized = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I can't get it solved, I want it to accept friend requests whenever I click my checkbox and disable the auto accept requests whenever I deselect the checkbox.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for this late reply, but the error message is actually very clear.

Your event subscription currently looks like this:

```
Private Sub oskype_userauthorizationrequestreceived(pUser As SKYPE4COMLib.User) Handles oSkype.UserAuthorizationRequestReceive
```

But the Skype4Com library's event is declared like this:

```
Public Event UserAuthorizationRequestReceived(sender As Object, e As AxSKYPE4COMLib._ISkypeEvents_UserAuthorizationRequestReceivedEvent)
```

As you might see you are missing one argument, and the second argument is of the wrong type.

The fix is simply changing the arguments to match the event:

```
Private Sub oskype_userauthorizationrequestreceived(sender As Object, e As AxSKYPE4COMLib._ISkypeEvents_UserAuthorizationRequestReceivedEvent) Handles oSkype.UserAuthorizationRequestReceive
```

I'd guess that you can extract the specific user if you look through the properties of the `e` argument.